New Relic: PostgreSQL Docker Container Logs Not Appearing in Dashboard
I'm trying to set up my PostgreSQL Docker container logs to be sent to New Relic. I've followed the setup instructions for the New Relic Infrastructure agent, but I am not seeing the expected logs in New Relic.
I installed the New Relic Infrastructure agent on my host machine.
Configured my PostgreSQL Docker container to generate logs.
Set up the New Relic log forwarding configuration for the PostgreSQL container.
Verified that the logs are being written to the expected locations in the container.
I am expecting to see PostgreSQL logs in New Relic like this:
2024-09-07 07:23:32.080 UTC [26] LOG:  shutting down
2024-09-07 07:23:32.449 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
2024-09-07 07:23:37.788 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-09-07 07:23:37.788 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432

However, I am not receiving any PostgreSQL logs in New Relic. The logs are not showing up in the New Relic dashboard or in the log forwarding output.

Please share more details about: "I installed .... Verified that the logs are being written to the expected locations in the container."   How did your verify that?

I checked inside the Docker container to find the file where all the logs are stored and verified that the logs are being written correctly.
